# Check how windows beforeunload event was fired - Keys pressed Or on closing browser

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, primeng

I am listening for the window´s `beforeunload` Event.

Then i want to determine whether beforeunload Event was fired by keys pressed (Ctrl+r/ F5) or by user closing the browser window.

in both cases i want the user to confirm with a custom dialog before the reload or closing of the window

the only thing in all this, i want to know about is - i guess - how to chain/catch those two events, hence `keys pressed` then `beforeunload` or `close browser` then `beforeunload`

```
fromEvent(window, 'beforeunload').subscribe(e => {
 e.preventDefault();
 e.returnValue = false;
 this.handleOnWindowUnload();
}
```

```
handleOnWindowUnload(): void {
  // case one: on reload by keys pressed, confirm reload in dialog, and then reload window

  // case two: on closing the browser, confirm in dialog, and then close browser
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A BeforeUnloadEvent does not seem to contain any information on the source (such as close window, key pressed, etc). You could try to tackle your problem instead by setting event listeners to e.g. keyboard input:

```js
fromEvent(window, 'beforeunload').subscribe(e => {
  console.log(e.key);
  // Note that this event contains the properties 'shiftKey' and 'ctrlKey' as well, so that you can check whether a combination of keys such as Ctrl+w was pressed)
});
```

and you'll have to combine this with the `beforeunload` event to see what the user did exactly.

Note that you can spawn a default confirmation popup, but I'm not sure if a custom dialog is possible. Browsers don't allow preventing someone from closing a window altogether, as that would be exploitable by malicious websites.

See the [specs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#examples) for more information and examples on the `beforeunload` event.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment. sorry, but had to rephrase my question, i put it in a stupid way. hope it s a better question now.